# Cannot enter text from class to textbox in form

Tags: c#, winforms

Cannot enter text from class to textbox in form.
We set a keypress event in the MyTreeView class.
The text box cannot contain characters.
What should I do?

*set of textBox1.
*Change Modifiers for textBox1 properties from private to public
*Change keypress event from private to public
*(It didn't work well, so I keep it private now.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace treeview
{

    public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {

        MyTreeView m_tree_view = new MyTreeView();

        public Form1()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[] tree1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[2];

                m_tree_view.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                m_tree_view.Size = ClientSize;
                m_tree_view.AllowDrop = true;

                tree1[0] = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("TreeNode1");
                tree1[1] = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("TreeNode2");

                m_tree_view.Nodes.Add("Node1");


                Controls.Add(m_tree_view);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        //This is the code I added.
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }


    public class MyTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    {

        public MyTreeView()
        {
            try
            {
                //This is the code I added.
                KeyPress += MyTreeView_KeyPress;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        //This is the code I added.
        private void MyTreeView_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("key_press_ok");

            //error code↓
            //textBox1.Text = "sample";
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: This is **not** C code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to click an button and then print some text i don't understand why you are making another class.
Will be good to make your code efficient and not complicated.
In the main class

```
private void SendText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "hi";
    }
```

But if you want to make it complicated and make a class you shuld return i variable and send it to the other class the you can use it.
Learn how to use Public and private first and then use them.
You shuld have a public class which send data and the private to recive and process.

Answer (score 0):

add (Exception ex) to your try catch.

so do:

```
try
{
    // your code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex, "Error in (add where the error is)");
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

So you will get a detailed Exception Message, maybe it helps you or maybe you will post it here, so we can see what the problem is.

And because you have System.Windows.Forms in your Using Directive

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

so

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[] tree1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[2];
```

is redundant and can be shortened to:

```
TreeNode[] tree1 = new TreeNode[2];
```